# Karma-Jasmine Error

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I have a following complex angularjs setup:

```
angular.module('a',['b','c'])
    .controller('c1', ['$scope', 'bservice', 'cservice', function($scope,bservice,cservice){

        // c1 controller code
    }]);

angular.module('b',['d','e'])
    .service('bservice', ['$scope', 'dservice', 'eservice', function($scope,dservice,eservice){

        // bservice code
    }]);

angular.module('c',['f','g'])
    .service('cservice', ['$scope', 'fservice', 'gservice', function($scope,fservice,gservice){

        // cservice code
    }]);

angular.module('d',[])
    .service('dservice', ['$scope', function($scope){

        // dservice code
    }]);

angular.module('e',[])
    .service('eservice', ['$scope', function($scope){

        // eservice code
    }]);

angular.module('f',[])
    .service('fservice', ['$scope', function($scope){

        // fservice code
    }]);

angular.module('g',[])
    .service('gservice', ['$scope', function($scope){

        // gservice code
    }]);
```

Now i am writing jasmine test case for the controller c1 , Here is my sample controller code

```
describe('c1 controller', function(){
        var scope, controller;
        var bservice, cservice;

        beforeEach( module('a') );

        beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, _$rootScope_, _bservice_, _cservice_) {
            scope = _$rootScope_.$new();

            controller = _$controller_('c1', {
                $scope: scope,
                bservice: _bservice_,
                cservice: _cservice_
            });

        }));

        it('scope should be defined', function() {
            expect(scope).toBeDefined();
        });

    });
```

But for some reason the test is failing and i am not getting any error message. The only message Firefox launcher shows is FAILED with following files:

```
minErr/<@ui-build/node_modules/angular/angular.js:68:12
loadModules/<@ui-build/node_modules/angular/angular.js:4779:15
forEach@ui-build/node_modules/angular/angular.js:357:11
loadModules@ui-build/node_modules/angular/angular.js:4740:5
createInjector@ui-build/node_modules/angular/angular.js:4662:19
WorkFn@ui-build/node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:3160:44
[3]</ContextKarma/this.loaded@http://localhost:9876/context.js:151:7
```

So my questions are:

**Can this kind of angularjs setup is advisable for testing and if yes what am I doing wrong or missing that is causing the test to fail ?**

**How can i enable detail error log in karma ?**

Comment: PhantomJS is known for swallowing errors, particularly in beforeEach blocks. Switch to Chrome. There's absolutely no reason to do things like `bservice: _bservice_`. It is already injected by default.

Comment: Ive been using chrome and firefox launchers but still the same error

Comment: Try to move `inject` from beforeEach to it and see what happens. I see nothing really wrong in the code you've posted - besides improper annotation, which hardly persists in original code. But this also means that real code can differ from the one you've posted.

Comment: @estus , yes your right, this is just a sample ive posted here, as for obvious reasons i cannot post the actual code, thanks for your reply though i will try your suggestion

Comment: I have only verbal evidences that error messages are truncated in Phantomjs but work normally in Chrome, never experienced it myself. But it is most likely that the problem is specific to beforeEach(inject(...)). If it will persist, try to catch it manually, like `beforeEach(() => { try { inject(...) } catch (err) { console.error(err) } })`.

Answer (score 1):

The very first thing that you've done wrong is: The name of dependencies, as it should have been strings instead of variables.

So, instead of:

```
angular.module('a',['b','c']).controller('c1', [$scope, bservice, cservice, function($scope,bservice,cservice){
        // c1 controller code
    }]);
```

It should be:

```
angular.module('a',['b','c']).controller('c1', ['$scope', 'bservice', 'cservice', function($scope,bservice,cservice){
        // c1 controller code
    }]);
```

The next thing you should do is test each service and controller separately by mocking the required one during the individual service and controllers' test.

Here is the [CodePen](http://codepen.io/gauravmahto/pen/GWKmpG?editors=1010) for the example. If, you'll mock the module and service properly it will work.

Comment: Please ignore the typos that may have been in my code.

Comment: @VishwaKumar Instead of downvoting fix the typos.

Comment: Check out the CodePen demo, I've added. According to me if you do what I've mentioned above it will work, at least it works in my example.

Comment: Thanks for your CodePen! I will try what you have mentioned

Comment: Man you are a life saver!! One question in your codepen there is this line `$provide.value('bservice', {});` , how do i get my actual service object in this line of code ? Thanks for your reply

Comment: @VishwaKumar So, assuming that your service expose methods like `doThis`, `doThat`, then you can create a local object(let name it `dummyService`) that should contain `doThis` and `doThat` methods which will act like dummy or partial function, mimicking actual service's methods. And then you can write `$provide.value('bservice', dummyService)` instead of `$provide.value('bservice', {})`. This way you can also spy on those dummy/mocked funtions and with help of spy you can test whether your controller/service are actually making calls to the service methods or not. Hope this will help.

Comment: Remember bringing the actual service is not always a good thing, better test that service in isolation. P. S. : Take this advice with a grain of salt.

Comment: So you mean i need to mock the service and its data instead of using actual service ??

Comment: Yes and No. The rule that I use is that if the service doesn't break the test of  controller/service/directive etc. then I don't mock it, but if it breaks then I would mock it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136450/discussion-between-gaurav-and-vishwakumar).